# Excel Formula to sum 12 most recent cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have an Excel formula question that I was hoping you could help me with.

Basically I have a set of numbers in the second row of my spreadsheet from A2 to CC2. However, as of now only A2 to BA2 are populated with numbers. BB2 onwards will be populated in the coming weeks. I need to have a formula in cell CD2 which only sums up the last 12 populated cells in row 2. In this case it would the sum of AP2 to BA2, but next week it would be AQ2 to BB2 & so on.

I would really appreciate it if you could please help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Ducky

Comment: Search on here, similar questions have been asked.

Comment: But I would find the last populated cell and use offset()...

Comment: @SolarMike Offset is volatile. There are better formulas.

Comment: @teylyn but it would work and something for the op to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A2:CC2,MATCH(1E+99,A2:CC2)-11):INDEX(A2:CC2,MATCH(1E+99,A2:CC2)))
```

It will find the last cell in the range that has a number and sum that cell and the 11 cells to the left.

Comment: @Scott Craner, Hi Scott, Can you please explain how the formula working? Wondering...

Comment: @Harun24HR take it apart and work out what each part does - an excellent learning experience.

Comment: @SolarMike I have done that already but wonder is both `Index()` function is returning numeric value. So, how it is summing ranges from these two numeric value.

Comment: @Harun24HR if index returns a numeric then it can be summed. Index will return whatever is in the cell, even text...

Comment: @Harun24HR Index when used in conjunction with `:` will, in Excel only, return the reference and not the value.  `A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))` will return a reference starting in `A1` until the last cell in Column `A:A` that has a number.

Comment: @Scott Understood. Learned new things. Thanks and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit less efficient solution (Array formula - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), but might also prove useful:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(COLUMN($A$2:$CC$2)>(COUNTA($A$2:$CC$2)-12),$A$2:$CC$2,0))
```

It only takes into account last 12 columns - `IF(COLUMN($A$2:$AA$2)>(COUNTA($A$2:$AA$2)-12),...` and then it sums their respective values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or, this shorter one,

in `CD2` :

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A2,,MATCH(9.9E+307,A2:CC2)-1,,-12))
```

p.s. Although Offset is volatile, it still can consider in case of formulas used not in a huge quantity.